# If $P_\mathcal{M} - P_\mathcal{N}$ is nonsingular, then $\mathcal{M}\oplus \mathcal{N}=\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Let $\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be nontrivial subspaces, and let $P_\mathcal{M}, P_\mathcal{N}$ be their respective orthogonal projectors.

I want to prove that if $P_\mathcal{M} - P_\mathcal{N}$ is nonsingular, then $\mathcal{M}\oplus \mathcal{N} = \mathbb{R}^n$.

**Attempt**:

We just need to show that $\mathcal{M}\cap \mathcal{N} = \{0\},$ and that $\mathcal{M} + \mathcal{N} = \mathbb{R}^n$.

First, let $x\in\mathcal{M}\cap \mathcal{N}$, then since $P_\mathcal{M}$ is an orthogonal projector onto $\mathcal{M}$, it follows that $P_\mathcal{M}x = x$. Similarly, $P_\mathcal{N}x = x$. Thus:
$$
(P_\mathcal{M} - P_\mathcal{N})x = x - x = 0 \implies x = 0 \implies \mathcal{M}\cap \mathcal{N} = \{0\}.
$$

Now, since $\operatorname{range}(P_\mathcal{M} - P_\mathcal{N})\subseteq \mathcal{M} + \mathcal{N},$
$$
n = \operatorname{rank}(P_\mathcal{M} - P_\mathcal{N})\leq\dim(\mathcal{M} + \mathcal{N})\leq n \implies \mathcal{M} + \mathcal{N} =\mathbb{R}^n,
$$
so finally $\mathcal{M}\oplus\mathcal{N} =\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Question**

This is actually exercise 5.15.6 from Meyer's "Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra" (free copy online available), but the solution to this problem given in the manual is a bit more convoluted than what I have above, so I wonder if I have a mistake somewhere in the above proof.

Comment: The proof seems valid and it looks like you don't even need the fact that the projectors are orthogonal.